# KendoUI Autocomplete with external datasource

Tags: autocomplete, datasource, kendo-ui

need some help before my brain explodes..
cant seem to understand what im doing wrong

have a quite simple autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data =new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "data/output.txt" 
        }
    });
  $("#input").kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: data
      });
        });
```

But no matter how hard i try i dont get the result i want, just the list with one letter vertical..?
I dont know how am the external file supposed to look? as now it just is:

```
"value1",
"value2",
"value3"
```

Comment: What does output.txt contain? Also why did you enable serverFiltering? Enabling it means that you will implement the filtering server-side which is impossible with a vanilla text file.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your dataSource thinks that the source is the string which is the content of that text document and it creates one item for each of the chars in the string.

Either use local binding like [here](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/110/edit).

Or create a service/action which will serve you the data as a proper json,odata or whatever. That text file which contains the symbols is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are returning the data is not the most convenient. You should try to return it as a JSON array:

```
[ 
    "text1",
    "text2",
    "text3"
]
```

But, KendoUI developers are really nice guys and allow you to define a `parse` function in the `DataSource.schema` where you can convert formats.

Try using the `DataSource` defined as follow:

```
var data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverFiltering:true,
    transport      :{
        read:"data/output.txt"
    },
    schema         :{
        parse:function (a) {
            return JSON.parse("[" + a + "]");
        }
    }
});
```